# $post return array() php

Tags: php, mysql, post

i'm trying to create a simple input program for an online site however when i try to insert data with 
query : `INSERT INTO tbl_integritytype (type) VALUE ('$type')`
With the `$type` it self is `$type=$_POST['ref22'];`.
But the output of the `$type` is always blank

i used :

```
<form action="insert_integrity.php" method="POST">
<tr class="content-specific-pg">
<td width="104" height="26"><div align="left" class="style6">
<div align="left">Type </div>
</div></td>
<td width="10"><div align="right" class="style6"> :</div></td>
<td width="126"><span class="style6">
<input type="text"  id="ref22" name="ref22"  size="20" class="easyui-textbox"/>
</span></td>
<td><td width="141"><input type="submit"/></td></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</form>
```

as the form.

when i try using `print_r($_post);` the output is

> array()

which i believe means empty.
However, if i set the `$type` into `$type="txt"`
the output in database will be

> txt

i can't seems to find the solution for this.
Please help me.
 Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Don't access directly to $_POST variables.

Comment: excuse me, i don't quite understand, care to explain ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 Instead do… what?

Comment: What Sfili_81 tried to say (and failed to...) is that it's a bad practice to concatenate your $_POST variables directly into SQL queries, as it's prone to `sql injection`, a.k.a. a malicious user can access your database through your page form. To solve this, take a look into `mysqli`'s or `PDO`'s prepared statement functions.

Comment: You need to stop creating faulty HTML first of all. You can not have `tr` as child of a `form` - either your `form` needs to go around the whole `table`, or completely reside within a single table cell.

Comment: Sorry i'm in a hurry and forgot a piece of comment :( tnx @Roberto

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow, I suggest you study some documentation about html, php and mysqli in https://w3schools.com

Comment: Your HTML code is an absolute mess. I suggest you fix that. Two open <td>'s, missing <table>, a </form> after a </td>. It `<form><table><tr><td>...*All* content here...</td></tr></table></form>`

Answer (score 0):

`post` array can't be accessed with `$_post` instead you should use `$_POST` to access `post` array

```
print_r($_POST)
```

Comment: Well, OP says it's `array()`, not *nothing*…

Comment: Shouldn't `$_post` be empty?

Comment: Sure. I'd rather suspect a typo/sloppiness in the question.

Comment: It should raise a E_NOTICE if using $_post, unless it has `display_errors` off

Comment: @RobertoMaldonado Yes it may be off

Answer (score 0):

Your input 'ref22' does not have a value.

```
<input type="text" id="ref22" name="ref22" value='xxx' size="20" />
                                          ^..........^
```

so the posted array will be empty.

Strip your form code down to bare minimum and test that your 'form' submits 'name:value's

```
<form action="insert_integrity.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ref22" value='123' />
    <input type="submit" name='submit' />
</form>
```